# Definition of modular Howe correspondence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, symplectic-group

Let $(G,G')$ be a pair of mutually centralized subgroups of a symplectic group $Sp_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (called a dual pair), and let $\omega_{G,G'}$ be the restriction of the Weil representation (with coefficients in a field $k$ of characteristic coprime with $q$) of it. We say that two representations $\pi$ of $G$, and $\pi'$ of $G'$ (with coefficients in $k$) are related by the (modular) Howe correspondence if
$$
Hom_{G\times G'}(\pi\otimes\pi',Hd(\omega_{G,G'}))\neq 0.
$$
That is, if $\pi\otimes\pi'$ is a submodule of the head of $\omega_{G,G'}$. Why do we need to use the head of $\omega_{G,G'}$ instead of $\omega_{G,G'}$ in the definition? (In zero characteristic we just use $\omega_{G,G'}$). If it is just because of the head is semisimple, then why could not we use the socle? Thank you in advance.